# camera2 pictures taken are blurred

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm experiencing a bad behavior when capturing a photo on a Samsung Galaxy S7 edge device.

I wait simultaneously for focus and exposure before taking the picture but at the end I have a kind of blurred image compared to the native camera app output.

The problem is especially visible on zoomed images but is present also when not zoomed. I've also tried to enable the optical image stabilization but the problem isn't fixed.

Below are linked sample images explaining the problem.

[Native camera image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guQED.jpg)

[My camera image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mbPq.jpg)

Here is the code:

Method for picture capture step 1:

```
public void capturePicture() {
    CameraState state = getState();
    if (state != IDLE && state != CLOSING && state != TAKE_PICTURE) {
            boolean af = false;
            boolean ae = false;
            if (isAFEnabled()) {
                af = true;
            } else if (isAEEnabled()) {
                ae = true;
            }

            if (!af && !ae) {
                takePicture();
            } else {
                triggerFocusAndExposure(true);
            }
    }

    return;
}
```

Method for triggering focus and exposure:

```
private void triggerFocusAndExposure(boolean picture) {
    setState(WAIT_PRECAPTURE_PICTURE);

    if (isAFEnabled()) {
        previewBuilder.set(CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
    }

    if (isAEEnabled()) {
        previewBuilder.set(CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER, CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER_START);
    }

    try {
        cameraSession.capture(previewBuilder.build(), new SCameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
            @Override public void onCaptureCompleted(SCameraCaptureSession session, SCaptureRequest request, STotalCaptureResult result) {
                setState(PRECAPTURE_TRIGGERED_PICTURE);
            }
        }, backgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        previewBuilder.set(CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_IDLE);
        previewBuilder.set(CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER, CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER_IDLE);
        cameraSession.setRepeatingRequest(previewBuilder.build(), mSessionCaptureCallback, backgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
    }
}
```

Methods for waiting focus and exposure:

```
private void waitPrecapture(STotalCaptureResult result, boolean picture) {
    // Check if AF/AE triggered and/or finished
    if ((!isAFTriggered(result) || isAfFinished(result)) && (!isAETriggered(result) || isAEFinished(result))) {
        takePicture();
    }
}

private boolean isAFTriggered(STotalCaptureResult result) {
    Integer afMode = result.get(SCaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_MODE);
    return afMode != CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF &&
            afMode != CONTROL_AF_MODE_EDOF;
}

private boolean isAfFinished(STotalCaptureResult result) {
    int afState = result.get(SCaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE);
    return afState == CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED || afState == CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED
            || afState == CONTROL_AF_STATE_PASSIVE_FOCUSED || afState == CONTROL_AF_STATE_PASSIVE_UNFOCUSED;
}

private boolean isAETriggered(STotalCaptureResult result) {
    boolean aeMode = result.get(SCaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_MODE) != SCaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF;
    return aeMode && cameraCharacteristics.get(SCameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL)
            != SCameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY;
}

private boolean isAEFinished(STotalCaptureResult result) {
    Integer aeState = result.get(SCaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
    return aeState == null || aeState == SCaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_CONVERGED || aeState == SCaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_FLASH_REQUIRED
            || aeState == SCaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_LOCKED;
}
```

Method for picture capture step 2:

```
public void takePicture(){
    imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(reader -> {
        Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
        buffer.get(bytes);
        image.close();
        singleSubscriber.onSuccess(bytes);
    }, imageSavingHandler);

    try {
        cameraSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), new SCameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
             @Override
             public void onCaptureCompleted(SCameraCaptureSession session, SCaptureRequest request, STotalCaptureResult result) {
                 if (getState() == CameraState.CLOSING) {
                     return;
                 }
                 cancelAF();
             }

             @Override
             public void onCaptureStarted(SCameraCaptureSession session, SCaptureRequest request, long timestamp, long frameNumber) {
                 super.onCaptureStarted(session, request, timestamp, frameNumber);
                 shutterCallback.call();
             }    

             @Override public void onCaptureFailed(SCameraCaptureSession session, SCaptureRequest request, SCaptureFailure failure) {
                  singleSubscriber.onError(new RuntimeException("Error taking picture, onCaptureFailed"));
                  if (getState() == CameraState.CLOSING) {
                      return;
                  }
                  cancelAF();
             }
         }, backgroundHandler);

         setState(CameraState.TAKE_PICTURE);
     } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
         singleSubscriber.onError(new RuntimeException("Error capturing image", e));
     }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting. `Thanks`. For what? This is a programming site. I see little programming.

Comment: Which tutorial did you use for the image capturing?

Comment: @Vyacheslav code added

Answer (score 8):

I've found the fix.
`captureBuilder` automatically sets `CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE_HIGH_QUALITY` and `CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE_HIGH_QUALITY` but in my case the device has some problem handling these options. Setting `CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE_FAST` and `CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE_FAST` fixes the problem.