# 2Seconds Delay for capturing image after clicking the capture button

Tags: android-camera2

Am working on application with custom camera with camera2 api. the problem is after clicking the capture button, the actual image is taken after 2 to 3 seconds.the phone should be kept still for 3 seconds in order to get required image.and quality of image is very poor

I have tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions...-of-captured-image-using-camera-2-api-android

[camera2 pictures taken are blurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39829528/camera2-pictures-taken-are-blurred)
for quality image  but none of them worked.

This is my takepicture() and createpreview()

```
 protected void takepicture() {
        lockFocus();
        if(null == cameraDevice) {
            Log.e(TAG, "cameraDevice is null");
            return;
        }
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
            Size[] jpegSizes = null;
            if (characteristics != null) {
                jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes( ImageFormat.JPEG);
            }
            int width = 640;
            int height = 480;
            if (jpegSizes != null && 0 < jpegSizes.length) {
                width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
                height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
            }
            ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
            List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList <Surface>(2);
            outputSurfaces.add(reader.getSurface());
            outputSurfaces.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));
            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
            //Flash
            if(isTorchOn){
                captureBuilder.set(captureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH);
           captureBuilder.set( CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE,CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_SINGLE );
            }else{
                captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);
                captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            }
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO);
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE,CameraMetadata.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE_HIGH_QUALITY);
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE, EDGE_MODE_HIGH_QUALITY);
            //setAutoFlash(captureBuilder);

            //Quality
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_QUALITY, (byte) 100 );
            // Orientation
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

                    Image image = null;
                    try {
                        image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        buffer.rewind();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                        buffer.get(bytes);
                        loadedImage1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray( bytes, 0, bytes.length );

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (image != null) {
                            image.close();
                        }
                    }
                }

            };
            reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, mBackgroundHandler);
            final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                               @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                               @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);

                    SimpleDocumentScannerActivity.startScanner(Custom_CameraActivity.this, pathCamera, "");
                    unlockFocus();
                }
            };
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    cameraCaptureSessions=session;
                    try {
                        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                        mState=STATE_WAITING_LOCK;
                        session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, mBackgroundHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                }
            }, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

this is createpreview().

protected void createCameraPreview() {
            try {
                SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
                assert texture != null;
                texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(), imageDimension.getHeight());
                Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
                captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
                captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE,CameraMetadata.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE_HIGH_QUALITY);
                captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE, EDGE_MODE_HIGH_QUALITY);
                captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
                cameraDevice.createCaptureSession( Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback(){
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        //The camera is already closed
                        if (null == cameraDevice) {
                            return;
                        }
                        // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                        cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                        updatePreview();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        Toast.makeText(Custom_CameraActivity.this, "Configuration change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, null);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

The expected result is after clicking capture button immediately image should be captured with good quality
Now a blurr image is capturing with time delay of 3 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem with Oppo phone, it takes 2 secs, but app works fine with Samsung and Nokia phones. What phones did you try this with ?

Also, this may be a problem with camera2 API and not older camera API.

Comment: I used oppo and redmi phones

Comment: I tested my solution on Samsung Note 5, Oppo F9 Pro (2 diff phones but same specs), Nokia 6.1. Only in Oppo does it not work as expected. I have a basic Redmi phone, maybe I will test it on it as well and let you know.